# User Control BringToFront() is not working

Tags: c#, winforms

`BringToFront()` is not working with my code. I have 2 user controls that I placed inside the form but the other one is not showing up.

I had tried the Show() but still it is not showing up.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelSide.Height = button1.Height;
        PanelSide.Top = button1.Top;
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
        uc1.BringToFront();
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelSide.Height = button2.Height;
        PanelSide.Top = button2.Top;
        UserControl2 uc2 = new UserControl2();
        uc2.BringToFront();
    }
```

Also, When I removed the UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1(), and write only UserControl1.BringToFront(); it will have an error. 
like this:

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.BringToFront()' c:\users\sheen\onedrive\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\Projects\StockSystemTrial\StockSystemTrial\AdminHome.cs  29  13  StockSystemTrial

Comment: Do not create __new__ controls when you actually want to refer to those you __already__ have! Use their names! write `uc2.BringToFront();`etc if these are their names. By default it will be `userControl11` and  `userControl21`, though

Comment: OK.Next step: Think of better names ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create **new** controls when you actually want to refer to those you **already** have!

Use their names! Write `uc2.BringToFront();` etc,  if these are their names.

By default it will be `userControl11` and `userControl21`, though, if you have two classes.

If there is only one class `UserControl` and two instances of it, they will be automatically named `userControl1` and `userControl2`.

I suggest picking better, speaking names, though..

Answer (score 1):

You must add the control to the form first like this

```
 this.Controls.Add(uc1);
```

Comment: Well, he wrote that he has them alreay on the form. In that case this will not really help..

Comment: @TaW yes, but when you create a new instance you must add it to the controls first

Comment: Yes but that may not be what he wants. Many newbies make this mistake and believe they can e.g. refer to their form by creating a reference to it but instead create a new instance..

Comment: @TaW, I don't know maybe we should let op speak for himself

Comment: Indeed. (Although the 1st line is very clear..) - ((You may want to consider expanding on your answer in case my comment to OP is right; feel free to intergrate it in your post))

Comment: Thank you :) It is my first time to code in C# language :)

Comment: @yoonsanha, your welcome I hope you become an advanced c# coder. Be sure to mark the answer as correct if it works for you

Comment: Your answer did not help him, he was just politely thanking you for your effort.